# angular-translate does not display character accent or umlaut correctly

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, translation

I started using angular-translate.  Works great!

But a translated character � is displayed for characters with umlaut or accent or ... (like ü or ú or ñ).   These same character values are displayed correctly in HTML text and as AngularJS variables.

Here's a sample output.  The output for html text and angular variable display correctly.  The results from $translate filter and directive don't display the correct umlaut character.

> html text - Und sie untersützt mehrere Sprachen!
>
> angular variable - Und sie untersützt mehrere Sprachen!
>
> $translate filter - Und sie unters�tzt mehrere Sprachen!
>
> $translate directive - Und sie unters�tzt mehrere Sprachen!

Here's the code:

```
'use strict';

var translations =
{
    "TEST_DE": "Und sie untersützt mehrere Sprachen!",
    "TEST_ES": "Menú Señor"
};

angular.module('testApp', ['testApp.controllers', 'pascalprecht.translate'])
  .config(['$translateProvider', function($translateProvider) {

      $translateProvider.translations({
        TEST_DE: "Und sie untersützt mehrere Sprachen!",
        TEST_ES: "Menú Señor"
      });

}]);

angular.module('testApp.controllers', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="testApp">
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">

     <title>Test angular-translate</title>

   </head>

   <body ng-controller="testAppController">

     <!-- Declare the view/controller router -->
     <div ng-view></div>

     <!-- angular files -->
     <script src="angular.js"></script>
     <script src="angular-translate.js"></script>
     <script src="ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.4.0.js"></script>

     <!-- Application routing file -->
     <script src="app.js"></script>

     <!-- Application Controller -->
     <script src="testAppController.js"></script>


     <!-- Test translations -->
     <br />
     html text - Und sie untersützt mehrere Sprachen!
     <br />
     angular variable - {{ testPhraseDE }}
     <br />
     $translate filter - {{ 'TEST_DE' | translate }}
     <br />
     $translate directive - <a translate="TEST_DE"> </a>

     <br />

     <br />
     html text - Menú Señor
     <br />
     angular variable - {{ testPhraseES }}
     <br />
     $translate filter - {{ 'TEST_ES' | translate }}
     <br />
     $translate directive - <a translate="TEST_ES"> </a>

   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 16):

Quick question but worth asking (as I always do this mistake :) ) are you sure that your JS file is saved and served by your server in an UTF-8 format? Because nothing seems wrong with your code. I even made it work without the � [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4Iqe3TIWlNH9ymkKMjVE?p=preview). Hope it's only that.

Comment: That is exactly the problem.  Thanks for trying the code and confirming that it was ok for you.  I checked and converted the code to UTF-8, re-entered the strings, and all is well.

Comment: I have the same problem, But can't understand how to resolve it, Can you please explain about that..

Comment: For those looking for more information, I resolved this by using Notepad++ to convert the file itself to UTF-8 encoding. In my case, it was a json file that I loaded in, but you might try whatever file contains your translations. No server settings required. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Also check your angular sanitize strategy: 
**`sanitize`**: `sanitizes HTML in the translation text using $sanitize` 
**`escape`**: `escapes HTML in the translation`
**`sanitizeParameters`**: `sanitizes HTML in the values of the interpolation parameters using $sanitize`
**`escapeParameters`**: `escapes HTML in the values of the interpolation parameters` http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/19_security You might need to use the escape strategy if you use umlauts.

Comment: @frhd thanks for pointing this out, it helped me to solve the problem in my case

Answer (score 5):

In my case the issue was that Eclipse STS was saving the JSON file with no UTF-8 format. I used Notepad++ to save it as JSON file. Now the accents and special characters are displayed correctly in the directive.