# Characters in JSON altered in Angular HTTP GET

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, http, utf-8

I am trying to get a JSON object from a restful service. When I plug the URL into my browser (Firefox or Chrome) I receive the JSON with the proper UTF-8 encoding:

```
    {"name":"Université"}
```

However, when I attempt to GET the same URL in my Angular app, the text is not properly encoded. This is the object printed out from the JavaScript console:

```
    { name: "Universit�"}
```

Here is the code I'm using in Angular:

```
  $http(

      {
        method: "GET",
        url: 'localhost:8080/my/url/location',
        headers : {

          "Accept":"application/json;charset=utf-8",
          "Accept-Charset":"charset=utf-8"

        }
      }

  ).success(function(data,status,headers,config){

    console.log(data);

    /* the rest of the success function */ 

  }).error(function(data,status,headers,config){

    /* the rest of the failure function */ 

  });
```

Any ideas? Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Do you get the same result when sending the get request without the headers?

Comment: Yes I do get the same results.

Comment: It seems like the problem could be related to the below previous question, are you sure the json file source is encoded in utf-8?


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20617117/angular-translate-does-not-display-character-accent-or-umlaut-correctly

Comment: That did the trick!! The JSON being sent by the server did not set the content type to `application/json; charset=UTF-8`. Thank you!

Comment: Being new to Stack Overflow, I'm not sure of the proper way to resolve this question. Do I answer my own question?

Comment: Well it's technically a duplicate, so you can just remove it if you want

Comment: @kroppian Yes, you can answer your own question and mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/4Iqe3TIWlNH9ymkKMjVE?p=preview might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not with the code, but rather that the source file for the JSON was not being encoded in UTF-8