# French accent display in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a variable defined in my services.js file and made available to my controller via a factory. This variable contains French accents. Here is an example:

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])
.factory('Telephone', function() {
    var telephone = 'Téléphone';
    return {
        getVariable: function() {
            return telephone;
        }
    };
 })
```

The problem is, when I display my variable in the controller via the scope, the accents are not formatted properly (I get some weird characters instead). Here is my controller:

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, Telephone) {
    $scope.telephone = Telephone.getVariable();
    console.log('Telephone = ' + $scope.telephone); //Here I get badly formmatted accents, something like T�l�phone instead of Téléphone
})
```

I have also the same problem when I display the variable in HTML. I get this: T�l�phone

All my HTML templates are properly encoded (UTF-8).

Thanks in advance your help.
Riadh

Comment: Encoding issues. Make sure you save your file as UTF-8, and make sure you serve your HTML with `<meta charset="utf-8"/>` (assuming HTML5)

Comment: Thanks Adam. I did that. The problem persists.

Comment: Then it would be good if you can create a JSfiddle to demonstrate the behaviour. (I still think it should be a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20617117/angular-translate-does-not-display-character-accent-or-umlaut-correctly?lq=1), and that we don't know the whole story...)

Comment: The problem is solved. It is a duplicate indeed, sorry I didn't see it!! I just changed the encoding with Sublime Text to UTF-8 and resaved the JS file in the server. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welp, someone else will have to close it then :P Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change é to Ã©. So the evaluation will translate Ã© back to é

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])
.factory('Telephone', function() {
    var telephone = 'TÃ©lÃ©phone';
    return {
        getVariable: function() {
            return telephone;
        }
    };
 })
```