# MSAL user claims special characters decoding errors

Tags: angular, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I'm getting incorrect values while getting user claims with accents e.g. "é" using MSAL with Angular.

**Example:** Expected claim value: `Maxime Gélinas`; Received claim value: `Maxime GÃ©linas`

Here is my code:

```
const idToken = this.msalService.getUser().idToken;
const userName = idToken.name;
```

When I copy the ID token from local storage and decode it with jwt.io it's fine so the **error isn't server side**.

By looking at [MsalService](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/src/msal.service.ts), it seems that the call `getUser()` is calling *msal* directly so it look like it's a *msal* issue and not an *msal-angular* issue.

Am I missing some hidden config or it's a library issue?

Comment: It's unicode issue. Try to save your file as UTF-8, and make sure you serve your HTML with `<meta charset="utf-8"/>`. See a simlilar post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32265485/french-accent-display-in-angular.

Comment: No. I see the characters like that in vscode debugger and chrome dev tools too.

Comment: Can you try to convert the encoded token into json by yourself and see what is the result? First get the id token from local storage (key=msal.idToken),then try to convert the payload section into object using atob function (natively available in browser). This way you will remove the dependency on msal library and will be easy to identify the root cause.

Comment: @PrateekKumarDalbehera Yes, we used this workaround and it works so I feel like it's a MSAL issue...

Answer (score 0):

Turn out `@azure/msal-angular` use a old version of `msal` i.e. 0.2.2 while the latest version is 1.2.1. We switched to `msal` instead of `@azure/msal-angular` and it fixed the problem.

Otherwise, you can use the following custom function to decode claims as pointed by @PrateekKumarDalbehera:

```
  // Since claims are not decoded properly while using `this.msalService.getUser().idToken`,
  // This function get the ID token from cache and decode it manually.
  // We are waiting for a better answer on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59688501/5960632.
  private getIdToken() {
    const encodedToken = this.msalService.getCacheStorage().getItem(Constants.idTokenKey);
    const base64Payload = encodedToken.split('.')[1].replace('-', '+').replace('_', '/');
    const jsonPayload = decodeURIComponent(
      Array.prototype.map.call(atob(base64Payload), (c: string) => '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2)).join(''),
    );
    return JSON.parse(jsonPayload);
  }
```